# Control Fancybox2 overlay fadeIn speed

Tags: jquery, fancybox, overlay, fadein

I'm using Fancybox v2.0.5 and can't figure out how to fade in the overlay slowly. The openSpeed parameter only controls the content fade speed,  but I want the entire thing fading in at that speed.

Here is my call:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    prevEffect  : 'none',
    nextEffect  : 'none',
    fitToView   : false,
    autoSize        : true,
    openEffect      : 'fade',
    openSpeed       : 1500,
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            opacity : 0.9,
            css : {
                'background-color' : '#fff'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I'm thinking one of the callbacks that fire before the content is loaded is the key, but I can't seem to target the overlay from any of these.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You control that within the `helpers`=>`overlay` option like

```
   helpers: {
    overlay: {
     opacity : 0.9,
     css : {'background-color' : '#fff'},
     speedIn: 1500, //<-- here you control the overlay speedIn
     speedOut: 1500//<-- here you control the overlay speedOut
    } // overlay
   } // helpers
```

**EDIT** (Sept 12, 2012) : The option `helpers =>overlay=>speedIn` has been removed since fancybox v2.1. It's still valid for v2.0.6 and below.