# Fancybox 2.1 Overlay fade in (speedIn) not working properly/bumpy

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

bit of a novice when it comes to JS and CSS, and have been trying to sort out my problem for a few days now, hopefully someone can help me out...

I've just updated from Fancybox 2.0.5 to 2.1.0.  When the iframe opens to show a video from Vimeo, the overlay, which is set to fade in (speedIn at 1000), comes in at 100% instead of a fading in. And just before the iframe is finished loading, the overlay briefly flashes off and on again. Through the helpers I'm able to control speedOut, opacity and color, but NOT the speedIn of the overlay.

I've tried it in Safari (v5.1.2) and Firefox (v12) on my mac and both have got the same problem. Here's a link to the website I'm working on. (click the image):

http://www.steinstie.com/Test/index.html

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Here's the code for the helpers:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox-iframe").fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'fade',
            closeEffect : 'fade',
            openSpeed   : 1000,
            closeSpeed  : 1000,
            padding     : 0,
            width       : 600,
            height      : 360,
            type        : 'iframe',
            autoSize    : false,
            fitToView   : false,
            // NICK H
            afterLoad: function(){
                  this.title = $(this.element).next('.newTitle').html();
            },
            // END NICK H
            helpers: {
            overlay: {
                    speedIn: 1000, //<-- here you control the overlay speedIn
                    speedOut: 1000,//<-- here you control the overlay speedOut
                    css: {'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)'}
                    }, // overlay

                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                }

                    } // helpers
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there seem no `beforeOpen` / `afterOpen` counterpart callbacks of `beforeClose` / `afterClose` (see documentation at http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/), but we can clone the overlay create function and add a custom fade in after the overlay is created:

```
// Alter fancyBox functions.
(function ($, F) {

  // Clone of original overlay creation function, but with overlay fade in animation.
  F.helpers.overlay.create = function(opts) {
    var parent;

    opts = $.extend({}, this.defaults, opts);

    if (this.overlay) {
      this.close();
    }

    parent = F.coming ? F.coming.parent : opts.parent;

    this.overlay = $('<div class="fancybox-overlay"></div>').appendTo( parent && parent.lenth ? parent : 'body' );
    this.fixed   = false;

    if (opts.fixed && F.defaults.fixed) {
      this.overlay.addClass('fancybox-overlay-fixed');

      this.fixed = true;
    }

    // Custom fade in.
    this.overlay.stop(true).hide().fadeIn();
  }

}(jQuery, jQuery.fancybox));
```

Be aware that this probrably works best when using the overlay in unlocked mode. When using locked mode (default for non touch devices), the `.fancybox-wrap` elements are placed inside the overlay element and this can cause double fade animation (depending on your animation settings): on the overlay and on the child wrapping elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom script look OK ... [I have answered that before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9913999) so try these :

1. Load a single instance of fancybox .... you are loading the [normal](http://www.steinstie.com/Test/source/jquery.fancybox.js) and the [packed](http://www.steinstie.com/Test/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js) version right now when you need only either of them (but not both).
2. Load fancybox js file **BEFORE** the media, thumbs and buttons helpers js files, otherwise you will get these js errors :

   ```
   Timestamp: 12/09/2012 10:25:58 AM
   Error: TypeError: F is undefined
   Source File: http://www.steinstie.com/Test/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js
   Line: 25
   ```

and

```
Timestamp: 12/09/2012 10:25:58 AM
Error: TypeError: F is undefined
Source File: http://www.steinstie.com/Test/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js
Line: 28
```

and

```
Timestamp: 12/09/2012 10:25:58 AM
Error: TypeError: F is undefined
Source File: http://www.steinstie.com/Test/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js
Line: 87
```

those errors may break your fancybox code.

**EDIT** : As for Fancybox 2.1, the overlay's `speedIn` option **seems to have been removed**. It was now introduced the overlay's fixed position (maybe this new estate was conflicting with the `speedIn` option)

The script posted (`overlay speedIn`) will work with fancybox 2.0.6 and below.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering so quickly! Really appreciate it. Unfortunately I still can't make it work after having followed both of the steps described above. I've updated the index page on the test site: http://www.steinstie.com/Test/index.html according to what you suggested.

Comment: @user1666427 : I am afraid you cannot use `speedIn` option with fancybox v2.1+ since it was removed, see my edited answer.

Comment: Aha, that explains it... Have now gone backwards to v 2.0.6 and the speedIn now works! But the original reason why I moved on to v2.1.0 has come back; a white 'flash'-frame whilst the iframe is loading its vimeo content. Before posting here, I had been looking high and low for a solution to the problem, but only found [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105359/flash-of-white-screen-before-page-iframe-loads) to earlier version of Fancybox. Guess this is a different question which should be posted elsewhere, but is there a simple workaround to this problem? Thanks again!